# Lines, slopes, linear equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Give an equation of a line with slope zero which passes through $(5,1)$. I know that $y=1$

But I don't understand the next two questions:

b) Give an equation of a line perpendicular to the first line which passes through $(6,1)$.

c) Then find the point of intersection between the 2 lines.

Comment: How do you call those straight lines that are perpendicular to horizontal lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line with zero slope, $y = 1$, is a horizontal line. So the line perpendicular to $y = 1$ passing through $(6, 1)$ is a vertical line, hence, its equation is given by $x = 6$.

Now, the one point at which these two lines intersect is when $$x = 6, \;y = 1 \iff \text{ at the point }\, (6, 1)$$

Comment: Oh I get it now! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, user95012!

Comment: @amWhy: Needs a TU w/the green check! +1

Answer (score 0):

For (b), note that a line is perpendicular to a horizontal line $\iff$ it's a vertical line.

For (c), you're given one point that they both pass through. Can two different lines meet more than once?